# The difference of CCDF between using the degree.distribution function in igraph and the ecdf function

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I used two methods to analyze the degree distribution of nodes in a network. One method is using degree.distribution function in igraph package. The other method is using ecdf function in R. These two results are similar. But when degree is more than 1000, these two results are different. 
Why are these two result different? Response will be appreciated.
[image: degree.distribution function in igraph]

[image: ecdf function in R]

Comment: You can look at the source code of these two functions to see what they do. They are really not difficult. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example